# Block certain users from login using Meteor's accounts-password

Tags: meteor

New Meteor user here. I would like to block former employees from being able to login to a Meteor web app. The login is implemented by the accounts-password package. Does it provide an API to do this easily, if I don't want to delete the users or manually change their password from the database?

I tried to look through Meteor's documentation but found no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a [validateLoginAttempt](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-validateLoginAttempt) function that checks a custom field in the user document, e.g., `disabled`, and return `false` accordingly.